# Squid: is there a way to log https urls in their entirety and/or block according to full url regex?

Tags: configuration, proxy, https, squid

It seems that squid only "sees" the domain name for https requests.

Is there any way to configure it so that the full url can be logged and/or matched within ACLs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no way.  It is within the encrypted channel.  There are other tools that permit you to perform a man-in-the-middle attack, which make this possible.  They are tricky to setup since they require you to setup a CA, and install a certificate on every client machine.